# Generic method. Sub classes only

Tags: java, generics

I have the following class hierarchy:

```
Base
    \
     +-- A
     |
     +-- B
     |
     +-- C
```

I want to design a single generic method that can accept any class derived from *Base*, e.g. *A, B, C ... Z* but not *Base* itself.

Is that possible and how?

P.S. The main idea is to do something like this:

```
public void<TYPE> myMethod(TYPE arg) {}
```

where: TYPE is any type derived from *Base* excluding it, and when method is being parametrized (is that the right word?) with say type *A*, no other argument types but *A* are allowed. Same for should apply *A .. Z*.

---

I've come up with some sort of an idea to do this.

1. I've made *Base* package-private
2. I've put the designed
   *Helper* class into that same package and made it blatantly simple:

   ```
   public class Helper<T extends Base> {
       public void myMethod(T item) {}
   }
   ```
3. I've moved all calling code to another package.

In that way I was able to disallow things like:

```
Helper<Base> helper = new Helper<>();
helper.myMethod(new A());
helper.myMethod(new B());
```

and it works like

```
Helper<A> helperA = new Helper<>();
Helper<B> helperB = new Helper<>();
Helper<Base> helperBase = new Helper<>(); // error

helperA.myMethod(new A());
helperA.myMethod(new B()); // error

helperB.myMethod(new B());
```

as was intended.

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: You can't do that. You could add an intermediate abstract class between Base and its subclasses. Will making `Base` abstract not "effectively" take care of that?

Comment: @ernest_k, I have updated a question to be more specific.

Comment: In which clas the method would be ?

Comment: @azro, in any other than those mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible. You can declare `Base` as `abstract` which will make it not instantiatable.

Comment: You can instantiate an abstract class, you'll just need to implement the methods that are abstract

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'll update my question to be more specific.

Comment: @azro That would be an anonymous class.

Comment: Declaring the base class `abstract` would not prevent anyone from writing "a single generic method that can accept any class derived from Base, e.g. A, B, C ... Z but not Base itself".

Comment: @azro that is still an anonymous class

Comment: But also instantiable, so does not solve the problem no ?

Comment: @azro That would be an instance of a subclass, not a direct instance of the base class.

Comment: @azro that is not base itself, but a subclass having implementation.

Comment: @azro `new Foo(){}` really means `new ? extends Foo { ... }`

Comment: No way to manage that. My point was that your proposed solution was based on inheritance of an abstract class - and therefore did not solve the OP.

Answer (score -2):

**your generic method should look like this**

```
public <T extends Base> void helloWorld(T args) {
if(args instanceof Base) 
   return;
System.out.println("do something with args");
}
```

Comment: A, B and C are children at the same level of Base, not C a child of B and B a child of A

Comment: Also, this wouldn't even compile. You have syntax error.